# ToStringBuilder append X appendSuper

Tags: java, append, apache-commons, tostring

in my classes when writing the toString() method I always use the **ToStringBuilder** from *org.apache.commons*

And when I'm extending other classes I use `appendSuper()` and then my `appends`

**The question:**

Are there are any real differences in doing:

```
appendSuper(super.toString())
```

instead of

```
append(super.toString())
```

Kind of dummy question.

*Cheers*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `ToStringStyle` implementation can render it differently when [appendSuper](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/ToStringStyle.html#appendSuper(java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.String)) is called from [append](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/ToStringStyle.html#append%28java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean[],%20java.lang.Boolean%29). No implementation of Apache commons lang 2.4 does it.